# 'ReferenceError: define is not defined' when testing Angular app with jest using ApplicationInsights-js

Tags: angular, unit-testing, jestjs, azure-application-insights

I am assigned to write unit tests for our **Angular** application in our team, and I have done the configuration and setup for ***jest*** and got the tests working. But as our team have integrated Microsoft's ***ApplicationInsights-js*** into our application, my tests started to fail. I can't share the code due to company policy, but I will share what I can.

I have searched in Stack Overflow for this problem regarding ***ApplicationInsights-js***, but there was no similar ones. But, I found this as a issue in the GitHub page of ***ApplicationInsights-js***. The issue is [here](https://github.com/microsoft/ApplicationInsights-JS/issues/476). I have tried adapting almost all the solutions there, but with no success. According to [this comment](https://github.com/microsoft/ApplicationInsights-JS/issues/476#issuecomment-468320127) of a member, according to my understanding, I tried changing the **module** to different ones in *tsconfig.json*, but it wasn't successful.

#### Here is my error stack trace.

```
  ● Test suite failed to run

    ReferenceError: define is not defined

      1 | import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
    > 2 | import { AppInsights } from 'applicationinsights-js';
        | ^
      3 | import { environment } from '../../environments/environment';
      4 |
      5 | @Injectable({

      at Object.<anonymous> (node_modules/applicationinsights-js/bundle/ai.module.js:215:1)
      at Object.<anonymous> (src/app/services/app-insights.service.ts:2:1)
      at Object.<anonymous> (src/app/login/login.component.ts:8:1)
      at Object.<anonymous> (src/app/login/login.component.spec.ts:3:1)
```

---

#### tsconfig.json file

```
{
    "compileOnSave": false,
    "compilerOptions": {
        "baseUrl": "./",
        "outDir": "./dist/out-tsc",
        "sourceMap": true,
        "declaration": false,
        "esModuleInterop": true,
        "module": "es2015",
        "moduleResolution": "node",
        "emitDecoratorMetadata": true,
        "experimentalDecorators": true,
        "importHelpers": true,
        "target": "es6",
        "types": ["node", "jest"],
        "typeRoots": ["node_modules/@types"],
        "lib": ["es2018", "dom"],
        "paths": {
            "cComponents": ["dist/cComponents"],
            "cComponents/*": ["dist/cComponents/*"]
        }
    }
}
```

---

> This is my ***ApplicationInsights-js*** version.
>   **"applicationinsights-js": "^1.0.20"**

This has become a show stopper for my unit-testing. Any help is appreciated. If the information is not enough, I will try my best to give more info abiding to the company policies.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is happening because the library is built as an AMD module. The latest SDK is delivered as UMD and so it would resolve this issue. If you cannot upgrade, there are a couple of options you can go with that were previously discussed [here](https://github.com/microsoft/ApplicationInsights-JS/issues/476)

1. Guard each call to appinsights with `if (AppInsights !== undefined)`
2. (copied from [here](https://github.com/microsoft/ApplicationInsights-JS/issues/476#issuecomment-392139127)): If you're using jest, adding an empty `applicationinsights-js.js` file to your __mocks__ folder fixes this issue. If you need to mock the `applicationinsights-js` functionality, you should be able to do that here as well. *Please note that __mocks__ is case-sensitive*. For more info about jest mocks, [see Jest Mock documentation](https://facebook.github.io/jest/docs/en/manual-mocks.html)

Comment: As I have mentioned, the applicationinsights-js version is 1.0.20. And node package manager site shows it is the latest version. It is not possible for me to change the source code guarding every app insights call. :(

Comment: I also added an empty `applicationinsights-js.js` file, but then the error goes away and the test is skipped automatically.

Comment: I checked your GitHub repo and got the understanding that applicationinsights-web is the new build of this package. Is this correct? Then, if I change the AppInsight instance syntax to the new version, will it be able to compile in UMD?